# How to build map for large json with unknown structure

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have large json data with unknown depth and I need to build a map in the following format of result.

```
const json = {
  1: {
    11: {
      111: [{ "111-0": "b" }, { "111-1": [{ "111-1-0": "vs" }] }],
      112: "asasd",
      ...
    },
    12: [{ "12-0": "sd" }],
    ...
  },
  2: [{ "2-0": "sd" }],
  ....
};

const result = {
  "1::11::111::A0::111-0": "b",
  "1::11::111::A1::111-1::A0::111-1-0": "vs",
  "1::11::112": "asasd",
  "1::12::A0::12-0": "sd",
  "2::A0::2-0": "sd",
};
```

I think recursion is a good way to solve this but I am not able to implement recursion properly.

This is my current progress. Which gives incorrect output.

```
const buildRecursion = (json, r, idx = 0, prev = "") => {
  Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
    prev += key + "::";
    if (Array.isArray(json[key])) {
      for (let [i, v] of json[key].entries()) {
        buildRecursion(v, r, i, prev);
      }
    } else if (typeof json[key] === "object") {
      buildRecursion(json[key], r, "", prev);
    } else {
      if (idx === "") {
        r[prev + "::" + key + "::"] = json[key];
      } else {
        r[prev + "::" + key + "::" + "::A" + idx] = json[key];
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad to say, you're on the right track. All I did was clean up your variables
(especialy your handling of `prev`) and it works fine.

Other notes,

- use `''` instead of `""` for strings
- consider using template strings (backticks) for concatenating strings instead of `+` when doing so is cleaner (more often than not).
- I renamed the vars `json` -> `input`, `r` -> `output`, `prev` -> `key` for clarity.

```js
let input = {
    1: {
        11: {
            111: [{"111-0": "b"}, {"111-1": [{"111-1-0": "vs"}]}],
            112: "asasd",
        },
        12: [{"12-0": "sd"}],
    },
    2: [{"2-0": "sd"}],
};

let buildRecursion = (input, output = {}, key = []) => {
    if (Array.isArray(input))
        input.forEach((v, i) =>
            buildRecursion(v, output, [...key, `A${i}`]));
    else if (typeof input === 'object')
        Object.entries(input).forEach(([k, v]) =>
            buildRecursion(v, output, [...key, k]));
    else
        output[key.join('::')] = input;
    return output;
};

let result = buildRecursion(input);
console.log(result);
// {
//  "1::11::111::A0::111-0": "b",
//  "1::11::111::A1::111-1::A0::111-1-0": "vs",
//  "1::11::112": "asasd",
//  "1::12::A0::12-0": "sd",
//  "2::A0::2-0": "sd",
// }
```

Comment: Note that the first case (`if (Array.isArray(input))  ... buildRecursion(...)`) is actually unnecessary.  The `Object.entries` call in the second case will do the same thing.

Comment: Almost, but then you'd wouldn't have the `A` in the key. E.g. the last entry in result would be `"2::0::2-0": "sd",` instead of `"2::A0::2-0": "sd"`

Comment: Oh, I entirely missed the A in the request too!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method and `forEach` if the value is array. Then you can use `Object.assign` to assign recursive call result to the accumulator of reduce which is the result object.

```js
const json = {"1":{"11":{"111":[{"111-0":"b"},{"111-1":[{"111-1-0":"vs"}]}],"112":"asasd"},"12":[{"12-0":"sd"}]},"2":[{"2-0":"sd"}]}

function f(data, prev = '') {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    const key = prev + (prev ? '::' : '') + k

    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        v.forEach((o, i) => Object.assign(r, f(o, key + `::A${i}`)))
      } else {
        Object.assign(r, f(v, key))
      }
    } else {
      r[key] = v
    }

    return r
  }, {})
}

const result = f(json);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

(Updated to handle a missing requirement for the `'A'` in the front of array indices.)

You can build this atop a function which associates deeper paths with the value for all leaf nodes.  I use [variants of this `pathEntries` function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries) in other answers, but the idea is simply to traverse the object, collecting leaf nodes and the paths that lead to it.

```js
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [[Array.isArray(obj) ? Number(k) : k, ... p], v])
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]
  

const compress = (obj) => 
  Object .fromEntries (
    pathEntries (obj) 
      .map (([p, v]) => [p.map(n => Number(n) === n ? 'A' + n : n) .join ('::') , v])
  )

const json = {1: {11: {111: [{ "111-0": "b" }, { "111-1": [{ "111-1-0": "vs" }] }], 112: "asasd", }, 12: [{ "12-0": "sd" }], }, 2: [{ "2-0": "sd" }]}

console .log (compress (json))
```

The result of `pathEntries` on your data would look like this:

```js
[
  [["1", "11", "111", 0, "111-0"], "b"], 
  [["1", "11", "111", 1, "111-1", 0, "111-1-0"], "vs"], 
  [["1", "11", "112"], "asasd"], 
  [["1", "12", 0, "12-0"], "sd"], 
  [["2", 0, "2-0"], "sd"]
]
```

Then `compress` maps those path arrays into strings, adding the `'A'` to the front of the numeric paths used for arrays and calls `Object .fromEntries` on those results.  If you're working in an environment without `Object .fromEntries` it's easy enough to shim.

While `compress` is specific to this requirement, `pathEntries` is fairly generic.